# How do I set up this API get request?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an API working which gets trivia questions from this site: https://opentdb.com/api_config.php. Here is my code:

```
if (auth && data.user == user && match('trivia', data.msg)) {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&token=d6685dc31db69e33eeb1c3828ffa2c587d5ec43dc6dd995ebefe85681796d149", function(data, status) {
      sock.chat("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
}
```

It doesn't 'sock.chat' anything, I am new to this so sorry if there is an obvious mistake. I am using this script on Tampermonkey on a website if that helps.

Comment: What's the error, did you check your console?

Comment: Nothing is output, if you put in that url into your browser it comes up with text but doesn't output to the console. Also it doesn't come up with an error.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example:

```js
const url = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&token=d6685dc31db69e33eeb1c3828ffa2c587d5ec43dc6dd995ebefe85681796d149";


fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json.results))
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Comment: It comes up with this for some reason: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Objec

Answer (score 1):

This code is working.

```js
$.get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&token=d6685dc31db69e33eeb1c3828ffa2c587d5ec43dc6dd995ebefe85681796d149", function(data, status) {
     console.log(data);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It still comes up with nothing, maybe because I'm using it with Tampermonkey?

Answer (score 0):

you can see detail of api response on below code.

```
$.get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&token=d6685dc31db69e33eeb1c3828ffa2c587d5ec43dc6dd995ebefe85681796d149", function(data, status) { 
 for(i = 0 ; i <data.results.length; i++){
     alert("category: " + data.results[i].category + "\n " +
           "correct_answer: " + data.results[i].correct_answer +  "\n "  +
           "difficulty: "+ data.results[i].difficulty +  "\n "  +
           "incorrect_answers: " + data.results[i].incorrect_answers.length +  "\n "  +
           "question: " + data.results[i].question +  "\n "  +
           "type: " + data.results[i].type +  "\n\n\n "  +
           "status: " + status);
 }
```

});

you can manipulate response with dom element instead of "alert" function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still comes up with nothing.. Is there any methods beside get?

Comment: are you add Jquery library in your HTML page?-----------                          
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>-----------you should "query-1.10.2.js" As to where the HTML file is located.